# Visio PasteSpecial returning compile error: Expected Function or variable

Tags: vba, visio

I'm trying to export a Visio chart as a PNG with a transparent background. I've had success in the past by exporting it to an SVG, opening it in Inkscape, deleting the background, and saving it like that. In the chart that I am currently working with, however, I have a lot of text with funky formatting that is not supported by Inkscape.

I resolved to convert all of my text to images before exporting to SVG, and I'm stuck at how I should do that. I first thought that I could copy and paste each text box as an image, but this would be impractical for several reasons; the biggest one being that each text box has a very precise location that I could not easily replicate by hand.

So I'm writing a macro to do it for me. The issue now is that I'm running into a compile error before I can even step through it. It's very likely that there are other errors in this as I haven't been able to debug it yet. Does anyone know why this is turning an error?

```
'Enable diagram services
Dim DiagramServices As Integer
Dim XLoc As String
Dim YLoc As String
Dim myPage As Visio.Page
Dim newShape As Visio.Shape

DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140 + visServiceVersion150
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
myPage = Application.ActiveWindow.Page


For Each myShape In myPage.Shapes
    If Not myShape.OneD Then
        myShape.Select
        XLoc = ""
        YLoc = ""
        If myShape.Text = "\S+" Then
            myShape.Copy
            XLoc = myShape.Cells("pinx")
            YLoc = myShape.Cells("piny")
            newShape = myPage.PasteSpecial(visPasteMetafile) '<--- Compile error: Expected Function or variable
            newShape.Cells("pinx") = XLoc
            newShape.Cells("piny") = YLoc
            myShape.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next

'Restore diagram services
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices
```

Comment: Several things I notice:  You need to `Set myPage = `.  You need to declare `myShape`.  You need to `Set newShape`.

Comment: Have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, then try compiling the project. Any new compile  errors? If so, you're missing local variable declarations.